# AWS SSM get-parameter-by-path Manipulate JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm, aws-parameter-store

I am trying to retrieve all the parameters under a specific path from the AWS Parameter store using the command below:

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path some-path --no-paginate
```

This returns me a JSON with a lot of fields I do not need. How can I use the `--query` to just retrieve the name and the value?

Any documentation on how can I use the `--query` parameter? I have tried passing `jq` query strings, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the fields from Parameters(Array) and later select the fields you want to get using `{key:value}` syntax:

```sh
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path %PATH% --no-paginate --region %REGION% --query "Parameters[].{Key:Name,Val:Value}" --output json
```

**Output Json:**

```
[
    {
        "Key": "/test/amit",
        "Val": "test1"
    },
    {
        "Key": "/test/amit1",
        "Val": "test2"
    }
]
```

Or in case you want the output in text, change `--output` to text.

**Output Text:**

```
/test/amit      test1
/test/amit1     test2
```

More info about [Controlling Command Output from the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Amit. Is there any documentation available for forming the query parameter?

Comment: Note anyway, if you have stored a json value as a parameter you will need to use `--output text` in order to get it back properly formatted in json. If you format the aws cli command itself in json (`--output json`) it'll be converted from json into json and you'll get it back with all the `\n` in it.